# What is causing "The version of this file is not compatible..." error message?

Tags: windows

I am compiling my code using 32-bit compiler running on a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional. My programs run flawlessly on all recent versions of Windows up to and including Windows 8. The programs are being installed on dozens of PC, different brands, different hardware - all under Windows 7, either 32 or 64 bit. Everything works fine. No virtual boxes. Not even a need to play with compatibility modes. Compile, copy file to destination folder, double-click - everything works!

On two occasions (so far) we've had the following error message popping up on certain laptops, in a completely reproducible manner:

"The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

It always happened on the same laptops it had happened before.
It appears that some OS configurations just happen to be messed up, and this message is triggered.
How can I avoid this error message? Which Windows settings can be adjusted?

Comment: What kind of source is this? .NET? Java? What compiler?

Comment: I am using bcc32 and ilink32 along with plain Win32 API. Don't understand why this matters, but thanks for your attention anyway.

Comment: It may not matter at all, but just in case there was something out of the ordinary, it might help ring a bell for someone. First thing that comes to my mind is an interfering antivirus product.

Comment: Also, plain win32 api would tend to eliminate the possible vagaries of a .config file as it would with a .NET executable. It might get tedious, but I'd suggest perhaps grabbing procmon against a working machine's startup of this app, and then compare it to a similar procmon run against the problem matchine starting the same application. It might point to a machine-specific library issue.